# Read More Asp.net Gridview issue

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am trying to add a Read More option to my news portal at the end of `brief` description of a news. As of now everything seems to be working fine 20 most recent records are displayed. But as soon as I add this piece of code in the gridview. Only the first record is displayed and the read more link doesnt seem to work.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlRead" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" 
        Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#0099FF" 
        NavigateUrl='<%# "news_details.aspx?id=" + Session["id"].ToString() %>'>Read More</asp:HyperLink>
```

This is what the ItemTemplate looks like

```
  <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="name3" runat="server" 
        CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" CommandName="news" 
        Font-Underline="False" Text='<%# Eval("headlines_n") %>' Font-Bold="True" 
        Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="#0D8CCF" />
  <asp:Label ID="Label21" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("nid") %>'></asp:Label>
 <br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
        CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" CommandName="news" 
        Font-Underline="False" Text='<%# Eval("brief") %>' />
     &nbsp;<asp:HyperLink runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" 
        Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#0099FF" 
        NavigateUrl='<%# "news_details.aspx?id=" + Session["id"].ToString() %>'> read more</asp:HyperLink>
     <br />
     <br />
</ItemTemplate>
```

This is the server side code :

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName.Trim())
    {
        case "news":
            try
            {
                int r1 = Int32.Parse((e.CommandArgument).ToString());
                r1 = r1 % 9;
                Label lbid1 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[r1].FindControl("Label21"); //Label 21 fetches the newsid from the database. 
                Session["id"] = lbid1.Text;
                Response.Redirect("news_details.aspx?id=" + Session["id"]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.ToString());

            }

            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share some server side code as well...

Comment: share full aspx of this page